# How do I decide at the tick frequency of an RTOS?

Tags: operating-system

If an RTOS has option to change the tick frequency any time at user level (say, with just an API), what are the parameters (to be considered) with which one arrives at the efficient tick frequency? If ticks are too fast, I would end up doing a lot of execution at Kernel level. If ticks are slow, I would miss the real time criteria. Should I do a profiling of the earliest time of some of the high priority ready threads? This isn't a particular OS, but a more generic question.

Answer (score 1):

usually, in a RTOS, one tick vary from 1ms to 10ms, depends on you requirement and your hardware platform; i don't think you need to change this value dynamically on the fly, of cause this can be implemented, but not needed, and there is no RTOS support this feature as i know;

if there need much timer in your soft, and the acuratest time base Y is among 1 to 10ms， then you can config the TICK as Nms ( 1 < N < 10, N < Y ).

if you need a timer has an acurate of 1 us or even 1 ns, I think hard timer is the right choice, and using ISR do you job as far as possible, or ISR + TASK, if this meet your requirements;

Bigger TICK value makes lower acurate time base, but it makes a lower system overhead at the same time;

Conversely, smaller TICK, you can get higher acurate time base, but it make a high system overhead;

if the TICK get down to some point, your system will not run, because your application can't get CPU time, CPU run the RTOS itself most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

The tick rate has to be fast enough to handle the desired responsiveness.

If your application requires timeouts/reschedules/delays ... in the order of microseconds, a tick rate of 1000 ticks/sec (1 tick/ms), will be too slow.  However, if your application is fine with delays of 50 ms, then a rate of 50000 ticks/sec is clearly overkill.

Most of the time, I think you can expect that your processor will be fast enough to handle the desired tick rate.  If it is not, then you probably either have to re-think (parts of) your code architecture and/or your hardware selection.

Hope this helps.